# l'écoles versus les écoles. Which is correct, and why?

Tags: grammaire

I have found on my notes "always use les écoles, never l'écoles".

But I don't remember why.

Is this correct? What is the grammatical rule that supports it?

Comment: *l’école**s*** est fautif ; ***“l’*** (élision du ***a*** à cause du ***é*** de) *é*cole” = “***la*** école”, le ***s*** de école indique le pluriel, il faut donc le supprimer pour être cohérent avec l’article.

Answer (score 5):

*Les écoles* (the schools) is correct.

*Écoles* is plural, therefore the article has to be plural too: *les*.

If *école* were singular (the school), then you'd say *l'école*.

Comment: so, there is never a liason with les+noun?

Comment: @josinalvo There may be a _liaison_ (like how there is a liaison in _ils ont_), but there is no _elision_ of the vowel. As a general rule, elision only occurs with certain words with a final vowel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the singular or the plural depending on the context.

```
"Les écoles sont fermées"

"L'école de ma fille est fermée."
```

In the first case I'm writing that either all schools (from kindergarten to universities) of all kind are closed or only elementary schools are closed.
In the second case, I'm writing that my daughter's school is closed, not saying anything about the others.